# Two JOINS on same table

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

I'm working on a website which shows the soccer score with two teams and two scores in my DB.

This is the code I have:

```
<?php 
        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM resultat 
        LEFT JOIN brukere ON resultat.dommer = brukere.id
        INNER JOIN lag ON resultat.lag1 = lag.id
            INNER JOIN lag ON resultat.lag2 = lag.id
        ORDER BY slutt DESC
        " )
        or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);if ($result) {while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
        ?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['klubb']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['klubb']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stilling1'] . " - " . $row['stilling2']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['roed'] . " rødt og " . $row['gult'] . " gult"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bane']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['navn']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
```

And I get:

> SELECT Error: Not unique table/alias: 'lag'

When I try:

```
INNER JOIN lag s ON resultat.lag1 = lag.id
INNER JOIN lag c ON resultat.lag2 = lag.id
```

I get:

> SELECT Error: Unknown column 'lag.id' in 'on clause'

How do I do it? Two joins from the same table

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: i know, but it is a school project and they want us to do it this way ...

Comment: does they want to get there database hacked by student ... ;p

Comment: Don't use "SELECT *". Instead, identify which columns you actually want returned and assign aliases accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the alias you just gave to your table `lag`. You assigned `s` at first join and `c` at second so you should use them

```
INNER JOIN lag s ON resultat.lag1 = s.id
INNER JOIN lag c ON resultat.lag2 = c.id
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great! One more question. I have set it up so it echo's out the result: $row['klubb/name'] this should be different now it shows the name twice, any ideas ?

Comment: so? $row['s.klubb'] and $row['c.klubb'] ?

Comment: don't select just *, put all the columns you need and then give an alias for the repeated ones, for example `select s.klub as s_klub, c.klub as c_klub....` then you can call them with `$row['s_klub']` and `$row['c_klub']

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine JOIN like this:

```
INNER JOIN lag ON resultat.lag1 = lag.id OR resultat.lag2 = lag.id
```

Replace OR with AND if you need

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-join and you need the alias in your expession:

```
     INNER JOIN lag s ON resultat.lag1 = s.id
     INNER JOIN lag c ON resultat.lag2 = c.id
```

In general you use self-joins with adjacency-list and to walk the tree down a dimension:

```
    SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
    FROM category AS t1
    LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
    WHERE t1.parent is NULL
```